# Creating a drop down menu in dash to filter by a column

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

Using the example from dash, how can i filter on one columns value (in this case countries) to create a drop down list to filter by that column. I want it such that when i filter on a country the graphs also update. Any ideas?

```
import pyodbc 
import plotly
from plotly.offline import *
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import __version__
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import itertools
#import ccxt
import json
import datetime as dt 

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder2007.csv')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-interactivity',
        columns=[
            {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True, "selectable": True} for i in df.columns
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        filter_action="native",
        sort_action="native",
        sort_mode="multi",
        column_selectable="single",
        row_selectable="multi",
        row_deletable=True,
        selected_columns=[],
        selected_rows=[],
        page_action="native",
        page_current= 0,
        page_size= 10,
    ),
    html.Div(id='datatable-interactivity-container')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-interactivity', 'style_data_conditional'),
    [Input('datatable-interactivity', 'selected_columns')]
)
def update_styles(selected_columns):
    return [{
        'if': { 'column_id': i },
        'background_color': '#D2F3FF'
    } for i in selected_columns]

@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-interactivity-container', "children"),
    [Input('datatable-interactivity', "derived_virtual_data"),
     Input('datatable-interactivity', "derived_virtual_selected_rows")])
def update_graphs(rows, derived_virtual_selected_rows):

    if derived_virtual_selected_rows is None:
        derived_virtual_selected_rows = []

    dff = df if rows is None else pd.DataFrame(rows)
    print(derived_virtual_selected_rows )
    colors = ['#7FDBFF' if i in derived_virtual_selected_rows else '#0074D9'
              for i in range(len(dff))]

    return [
        dcc.Graph(
            id=column,
            figure={
                "data": [
                    {
                        "x": dff["country"],
                        "y": dff[column],
                        "type": "bar",
                        "marker": {"color": colors},
                    }
                ],
                "layout": {
                    "xaxis": {"automargin": True},
                    "yaxis": {
                        "automargin": True,
                        "title": {"text": column}
                    },
                    "height": 250,
                    "margin": {"t": 10, "l": 10, "r": 10},
                },
            },
        )
        # check if column exists - user may have deleted it
        # If `column.deletable=False`, then you don't
        # need to do this check.
        for column in ["pop", "lifeExp", "gdpPercap"] if column in dff
    ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False,ssl_context='adhoc')
```

Not sure how I can edit this, unless somebody has some documentation on how i can create this drop down

Comment: i.e. replace the `DataTable` by a `Dropdown` and highlight the selected country?